# group by for sum averages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

> source     year    country    numObserved    average 
>     ---           ---          ---            ---                     --- 
>     abc                2016           us                    30                                 15
>     abc               2017           us                    10                                 20
>   
>   pqr          2016        us              50                     40 
>   pqr         2017       ru             12
>                        26
> ...

There can be multiple sources and multiple countries within each `source`.
I want the output in the form of:

> year        country      avg  
>     ---          ---              --- 
>   2016       us             30.625 
>   2017      us            20 
>   2017      ru            26

where avg is computed as  Σ(`numObserved`*`average`) / Σ`(numObserved`) for any given pair of `year` and `country`

The `avg(average)` on `group by year, country` doesn't work because it takes the average of 15, 40 (i.e. 27.5) for `year = 2016` and `country = us`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I have tried group by year, country and then applied aggregate function avg on average, but it takes the averages of average i.e. (avg1 + avg2 + ... avgn) / n , which is not what I want.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to "roll your own" weighted average rather than relying on the built in `avg` function:

```
SELECT
    country,
    year,
    SUM(numObserved * average) / SUM(numObserved) AS weighted_average
FROM my_table
GROUP BY country, year
```